Getting method hardhat_impersonateAccount not supported when impersonating a WETH whale account on Arbitrum
Attempting to impersonate a WETH whale account on arbitrum and getting:
ProviderError: method hardhat_impersonateAccount not supported

The code is being run from a script using the following command in a VS Code Terminal Windows:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_prod.ts --network arbitrum

This is my hardhat.config.ts file:
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const mainnet_provider_url = process.env.MAINNET_PROVIDER_URL!;
const testnet_provider_url = process.env.TESTNET_PROVIDER_URL!;
const arbitrum_provider_url = process.env.ARBITRUM_PROVIDER_URL!;
const private_key = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY!;

console.log(mainnet_provider_url);
console.log(testnet_provider_url);
console.log(arbitrum_provider_url);

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.10" }, { version: "0.8.13" }],
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: arbitrum_provider_url,
      },
    },
    testnet: {
      url: testnet_provider_url,
      chainId: 97,
      accounts: [private_key],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: mainnet_provider_url,
      chainId: 56,
      accounts: [private_key],
    },
    arbitrum: {
      url: arbitrum_provider_url,
      chainId: 42161,
      accounts: [private_key],
    },
  },
};

export default config;


The provider being referred to in my .env file is:
ARBITRUM_PROVIDER_URL=https://arbitrum.llamarpc.com

Code fails on this request...
    // Impersonate Whale Account --- CODE FAILS HERE.
    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: [WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN],
    });

This is the full code that I'm trying to run in scripts/deploy_prod.ts:
import { loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers, network } from "hardhat";
import { abi as abiFlashLoan } from "../artifacts/contracts/FlashLoan.sol/FlashLoan.json";

//Abitrum Tokens 
const WETH = "0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1";
const BORROW_TOKEN = WETH;

const WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN = "0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1";

async function main() {

  // Impersonate the whale and whale wallet 
  let { whaleWallet } = await loadFixture(createWhale);
  console.log("Whale Wallet Created Balance \t",whaleWallet.getBalance());

}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});


// Impersonate the Whale Account 

async function createWhale() {

  const provider = ethers.provider;

    // Ensure balance not zero (for making transactions)
    const whaleBalance = await provider.getBalance(WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN);
    console.log ("Whale Balance: \t", whaleBalance.toString());
    expect(whaleBalance).not.equal("0");

    // Impersonate Whale Account --- CODE FAILS HERE.
    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: [WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN],
    });

    // Get Information on Wallet. 
    const whaleWallet = ethers.provider.getSigner(WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN);
    console.log("Network Used for createWhale: \t",(await provider.getNetwork()).name.toString());
    console.log("ChainId Used for createWhale: \t",(await provider.getNetwork()).chainId.toString());
    expect(await whaleWallet.getBalance()).not.equal("0");

    // Ensure balance is present
    const abi = [
      "function balanceOf(address _owner) view returns (uint256 balance)",
    ];

    const contractBorrow = new ethers.Contract(BORROW_TOKEN, abi, provider);
    const balance  = await contractBorrow.balanceOf(WHALE_ADDR_TOKEN);
    console.log("Balance of BorrowedEndToken \t", balance.toString())
    expect(balance).not.equal("0");

    return { whaleWallet };


    }


I suspect that hardhat may be trying to impersonate the account on the arbitrum mainnet, which isn't allowed--not clear on that point, but I'm not sure how I can switch between a local fork of the arbitrum mainnet to do the impersonation function call when the script is typescript is running and after I've called it with "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_prod.ts --network arbitrum"   How do I switch over to the local fork negating the switch value that I passed in to use the arbitrum mainnet?

Because you're running forking on hardhat network like your config, you should change:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_prod.ts --network arbitrum

->
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_prod.ts

